# Requests does not load all the html

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

Im trying to use requests to sign into a page, but in order to do so i need the csrf token from the page. When im in my normal browser I am able to see the token in the html, same with selenium, but as soon as I try with requests the token does not load in the html.

Comment: You can get that token with requests. What's the url?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.